# Помогите, PHP записывает в текстовую БД лишнюю информацию

Tags: php

Есть бд такого типа(текстовая)

```
    Id:Спб:
 ...
 Город: спб

   Имя: тупак

 о себе: кодер
 ...

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ank.css">

<form action="ank.php" method="post">
Добавить<br/>
<input placeholder="Город." type="text" name="gorod" /><br/>
<input placeholder="Имя." type="text" name="datavnes" /><br/>
<input placeholder="Пол." type="text" name="datapost" /><br/>
<input placeholder="О себе." type="text" name="jur" /><br/>
<input placeholder="Соц сети." type="text" name="summ" /><br/>
<input placeholder="Ищу..." type="text" name="numberpp" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="bth" value="Отправить.">
<div class="a">
  <a href="index.php">На главную!</a>

</div>
</form>
<?
$datavnes=$_POST['datavnes'];
$datapost = $_POST['datapost'];
$jur = $_POST['jur'];
$summ = $_POST['summ'];
$numberpp = $_POST['numberpp'];
$org = $_POST['org'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$man = $_POST['man'];
$gorod = $_POST['gorod'];
$file_change="\n
Id:$gorod:
...
Город: $gorod
Имя: $datavnes
Пол: $datapost
О себе: $jur
Соц. сети: $summ
Ищу: $numberpp
...
";
$file=fopen("bd.txt", "a+");
fputs($file,$file_change."\r");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Если заполнить все поля, то он создает одну как надо но одновременно пустую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
# Читаем
function file_read($file) {
    $buffer = "";

    if(is_file($file)) {
        $buffer .= file_get_contents($file);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

# Пишем
function write_file($file, $context) {
    $f = fopen($file, "w+");
    if(is_writable($file) && is_resource($f)) {
        fwrite($f, $context);
    }
    fclose($f);
}

// Вот тут у Вас была ошибка. Не проверяли использовали ли форму или просто зашли на страницу. 
// Вообще Вам стоит проверять все вводимые пользователями данные. Иначе Вам могут отправить код, который испортит Вашу БД или выдаст её злоумышленнику.
if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
    $datavnes    = $_POST['datavnes'];
    $datapost    = $_POST['datapost'];
    $jur         = $_POST['jur'];
    $summ        = $_POST['summ'];
    $numberpp    = $_POST['numberpp'];
    $org         = $_POST['org'];
    $notes       = $_POST['notes'];
    $man         = $_POST['man'];
    $gorod       = $_POST['gorod'];

    $file_change = "\r\nId:{$gorod}\r\n...\r\nГород: {$gorod}\r\nИмя: {$datavnes}\r\nПол: {$datapost}\r\nО себе: {$jur}\r\nСоц. сети: {$summ}\r\nИщу: {$numberpp}\r\n...";

    # считываем что есть
    $bd = file_read("bd.txt");
    # склеиваем в единое
    $new_bd = $bd.$file_change;

    # записываем
    write_file("bd.txt", $new_bd);
}
```